# Unable to recover typeclass instances for types with kind F[A1, A2] with syntax extensions

Tags: scala, typeclass, ammonite

I've been playing around with the typeclass pattern in Scala to better understand how it works, as I'm familiar with Scalaz and wanted to figure out how it works "under the hood".

(You can run the following code with https://ammonite.io/ REPL)

```scala
import $plugin.$ivy.`org.spire-math::kind-projector:0.9.3`

sealed trait Maybe[+A] // Option
final case class Just[+A](value: A) extends Maybe[A]
final case object Null extends Maybe[Nothing]

sealed trait Direction[+E, +A] // Either
final case class Up[+E, +A](value: A) extends Direction[E, A]
final case class Down[+E, +A](value: E) extends Direction[E, A]

trait Functor[F[_]] {
  def map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]
}

object FunctorSyntax {
  implicit final class FunctorExtensions[F[_], A](private val self: F[A]) extends AnyVal {
    def map[B](f: A => B)(implicit instance: Functor[F]): F[B] = {
      instance.map(self)(f)
    }
  }
}

object FunctorInstances {
  implicit val maybeFunctorInstance: Functor[Maybe] = new Functor[Maybe] {
    def map[A, B](fa: Maybe[A])(f: A => B): Maybe[B] = fa match {
      case Just(a) => Just(f(a))
      case n@Null => n
    }
  }

  implicit def directionFunctorInstance[E]: Functor[Direction[E, ?]] = new Functor[Direction[E, ?]] {
    def map[A, B](fa: Direction[E, A])(f: A => B): Direction[E, B] = fa match {
      case Up(a) => Up(f(a))
      case Down(e) => Down(e)
    }
  }
}
```

So I've written some analogues to `Option` (`Maybe`) and `Either` (`Direction`), the `Functor` definition, some instances for `Functor`, some some syntax extensions so I can call `.map` on valid functors.

The following code works:

```scala
import FunctorInstances._
import FunctorSyntax._

val x: Maybe[Int] = Just(5)

println(x.map(_ + 1)) // prints "Just(6)"
```

as expected. But the following does not:

```scala
val y: Direction[String, Int] = Up(5)

println(y.map(_ + 1)) // errors out
```

throwing the error `help.sc:48: value map is not a member of ammonite.$file.help.Direction[String,Int]`

Simply put, I do not want this error to happen, and for `.map` to work on an arbitrary `Direction[E, ?]`.

I'm thinking that Scala isn't able to see that `Direction[String, Int]` can be destructured into a `F = Direction[String, ?]` and `A = String`, preventing the `FunctorExtensions` class from wrapping itself around the `val y: Direction[String, Int]`. Unfortunately, I do not know how to fix this.

NB: the instance itself is still recoverable with an `implicitly`

```scala
val instance = implicitly[Functor[Direction[String, ?]]]
println(instance.map(y)(_ + 1)) // prints "Up(6)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably missing the `-Ypartial-unification` scalac option if you are using Scala 2.11 or Scala 2.12.

Add `scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification"` to your build or you could use Scala 2.13 which has it on by default.

See https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/v1.6.1/README.md#getting-started

Comment: Adding `interp.configureCompiler(_.settings.YpartialUnification.value = true)` to the top of the file didn't seem to fix it :(

Comment: On ammonite you need to enable the flag before you script stars running. For example, on the Ammonite predef.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me with the following setup:

```
Welcome to the Ammonite Repl 1.6.3
(Scala 2.12.8 Java 1.8.0_141)
```

[image: Adding interp settings seemed to work]